# Symbol/notation for permutations similar to the $x \choose y$ symbol for combinations?

Tags: permutations, notation, combinations

With combinations ($_{x}C_{y}$), one can notate them via $x \choose y$.

With permutations ($_{x}P_{y}$), is there a notation similar to that of combinations?  Or should one always write $_{x}P_{y}$ or $P(x, y)$?

Comment: Re the cited article in the answer of Siong Thye Goh, specifically see the **k-permutations of n** section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) shows us other alternatives. In particular we can also write it as $(x)_y$ and $x^{\underline{y}}$.

It is important to be clear and we should use the common notation to avoid confusion.